# SQL query users using more than 2 devices

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm struggling with a SQL query, I am far to be an expert, long time I haven't done any SQL, so I appreciate the help!!!

The data I've got are like

```
Username  DeviceName

John      Laptop
John      Workstation
John      Workstation
John      Workstation
John      Workstation1
John      Workstation1
John      Workstation1
John      ThinClient
Julien    Laptop2
Julien    Workstation7
Julien    Workstation7
Julien    ThinClient
Julien    ThinClient
Julien    ThinClient
Julien    ThinClient
Andrew    ThinClient
Andrew    ThinClient1
Andrew    Thinclient2
```

What I am trying to find out is users using more than 2 devices when one of those devices is a laptop, that's the difficult part (for me), the desired result will look like

```
John      Workstation
John      Workstation1
John      laptop
John      ThinClient 
Julien    Laptop2
Julien    Workstation7
Julien    ThinClient
```

Andrew won't be listed as it doesn't have a laptop (DeviceName like Laptop).

Thanks a lot for your help, so far all my code is not working and I can't really find a way doing it with my current knowledge.

Cheers,
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your conditions translate readily to a query.  Because you want something close to the original rows, I think window functions make this easier:

```
with ud as (
      select distinct username, devicename
      from data
     )
select ud.*
from (select ud.*, count(*) over (partition by username) as numDevices,
             sum(case when devicename like 'Laptop%' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by username) as numLaptops
      from ud
     ) ud
where numLaptops > 0 and numDevices > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff! It works perfectly, exactly what I wanted, well done!! The only thing I change is put a like for devicename like 'Laptop%'. Once again thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You can find the relevant username using aggregation and conditional count (or sum) and then get corresponding rows by using an `IN` clause

```
select distinct *
from your_table
where username in (
        select username
        from your_table
        group by username
        having count(case 
                    when devicename like 'Laptop%'
                        then 1
                    end) > 0
            and count(distinct devicename) > 2
        )
order by username;
```

Comment: This returns the laptop entries themselves, which I believe their sample output excluded (though I'm not sure why).

Comment: Thanks @GurV - However it doesn't return the desired result. What you miss is the query needs to return the users + devices ONLY if one of them is a laptop. I am trying to find out if a user uses a laptop and another device. Your result return everything except laptop.

Comment: @kdjldjd - Removing the last filter condition should do. Updated the answer. Please try now?

Comment: @GurV - John Laptop was not present because I miss it! Sorry about that, I have edited my original post. I tried your query and it works! Thanks a lot for your effort! It is an accepted answer however I can't accept more than 1 answer ... and I have already accepted the other one that work first.

Comment: @kdjldjd - I originally answer it this way only. Anyway, glad I could help out. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just get the list of laptop users, then from that list, find anyone who also has a non-laptop device.  Here's a self-contained test script.

```
declare @t table(username nvarchar(100),devicename nvarchar(100));
insert into @t select 'John','Laptop'
insert into @t select 'John','Workstation'
insert into @t select 'John','Workstation'
insert into @t select 'John','Workstation'
insert into @t select 'John','Workstation1'
insert into @t select 'John','Workstation1'
insert into @t select 'John','Workstation1'
insert into @t select 'John','ThinClient'
insert into @t select 'Julien','Laptop2'
insert into @t select 'Julien','Workstation7'
insert into @t select 'Julien','Workstation7'
insert into @t select 'Julien','ThinClient'
insert into @t select 'Julien','ThinClient'
insert into @t select 'Julien','ThinClient'
insert into @t select 'Julien','ThinClient'
insert into @t select 'Andrew','ThinClient'
insert into @t select 'Andrew','ThinClient1'
insert into @t select 'Andrew','Thinclient2'
insert into @t select 'Bob','Laptop9'

select distinct
  username, devicename
from @t
where username in(select username from @t where devicename like 'laptop%')     --they have a laptop
  and username in(select username from @t where devicename not like 'laptop%') --they also have a non-laptop
```

Comment: Thanks @JosephStyons, I tried both query and it doesn't return the desired result.  What you miss is the query needs to return the users + devices ONLY if one of them is a laptop. I am trying to find out if a user uses a laptop and another device. Your result return everything except laptop

Comment: @kdjldjd in your original example output, should there be an entry with "John/Laptop"?  I have updated my answer to show all users and devices where they have a laptop + at least one non-laptop.

Comment: Yes indeed my bad, sorry about that ... I have edited my main post. I tried your query and it works! I wish I could accept more than 1 answer, thanks a lot for your help JosephStyons! :)